# How to pass/send a token from frontend to backend (using href?) for NodeJS verify if the EJS should render the page or not?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I'm creating a NodeJS application and I using a MVC pattern:

```
> src
>> [models]
>> [controllers]
>> [views]
> app.js
> router.js
> server.js
```

At the same repository, I have the controllers and models that is my API endpoints (controllers to call models and models that connects to database), and I have the folder "views" that is my HTML/CSS/JS files that was rendered by ***Template Engine EJS***.

My **router.js** can clarify:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const viewController = require('./controllers/viewsController');
const dashboardController = require('./controllers/dashboardController');
const groupController = require('./controllers/groupController');
const userController = require('./controllers/userController');

//VIEWS
router.get('/', viewController.home);
router.get('/func/dashboards', viewController.dashboards);
router.get('/security/group', viewController.group);
router.get('/security/user', viewController.user);

//API
router.get('/api/dashboards', dashboardController.selectAllDashboard);
router.get('/api/dashboards/:id', dashboardController.selectOneDashboard);
router.post('/api/dashboards', dashboardController.insertDashboard);
router.delete('/api/dashboards/:id', dashboardController.deleteDashboard);
router.put('/api/dashboards/:id', dashboardController.updateDashboard);

...the endpoints repeat at this point
```

As you can see, using the same router, I render some pages using EJS (viewController) and call some functions that is my API's endpoint.

Here a example of **viewController**:

```
const user = (request, response) => {
    response.render('security/user', {
        path: ['Security', 'User']
    });
};

const group = (request, response) => {
    response.render('security/group', {
        path: ['Security', 'Group']
    });
};

const dashboard  = (request, response) => {
    response.render('func/dashboard', {
        path: ['Funcionality', 'Dashboard']
    });
};

module.exports = {
    user,
    group,
    dashboard
}
```

Knowing that, I have a file named **sidebar.js** that contains my sidebar and menu, a normal HTML/CSS like the following:

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/func/dashboards">Dashboards</a></li>
    <li><a href="/security/group">Security > Group</a></li>
    <li><a href="/security/user">Security > User</a></li>
</ul>
```

**My question is:** How can I pass/send a token (that is in localStorage) from ***sidebar.js*** (frontend) to my backend ***router.js***?

I wanna do this because I want to add a middleware before EJS render the page, I will check if the user has permission to access this page, if not, the EJS will not render the page and block user to access (I will check permission in API too), but I want to add this security policy in 2 locations (API and before render the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good way to do this.

The closest you could get (and I strongly advise **not** doing this) would be to:

1. Read the value from localStorage
2. Search the DOM for links
3. Rewrite the `href` properties of each to add the token to the query string

but that would leak the credentials if anyone shared a link, harm caching, and put credentials that would expire in people's bookmarks. So again, **don't do that**.

---

For a traditional web app, made up of distinct pages, don't use localStorage to store your credentials. Use cookies instead (preferably as part of a session). They are stored by the browser and sent with requests automatically.

You might consider using the [Cookie strategy from Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-cookie/).

Comment: Thanks for helping me @Quentin!
Your advice to don't use this ideia and your nice tip to use cookies and the perfect timing to tell me that "cookies are sent with requests automatically" help me a lot. I didn't know that the cookies are sent automatically and I change my ideia to use cookis, setCookie ... and it will work nicely. Thanks man!